# What does it mean when Shukadeva says IKSHVAKU was born from nose of MANU?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, manu

Srimad Bhagavatam Chapter 9.6 shloka 4 .

क्षुवतस्तु मनोर्जज्ञे इक्ष्वाकुर्घ्राणतः सुतः ।
तस्य पुत्रशतज्येष्ठा विकुक्षिनिमिदण्डकाः ॥ ४॥

What did shukadeva mean when he says that ikshavaku was born from the nose of manu while sneezing ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You mean how can anyone be born via sneezing? Is there a rational explanation? We have [9.1.11-12](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/1/11-12/) saying it was a natural birth.

Comment: @sv What is "rational explanation" - an explanation that has to fit within the constraints of your personal limited knowledge/experience ? If someone who has never seen birds asked you *"how can anyone be born via egg"*, your answer will be *'that's just the way it is. just because YOU haven't seen one, that does not make the birth any way less rational'. There are 4 births mentioned in Vedas - anda (egg), sveta (sweat), beeja (seed), and womb. sneeze could be part of sweat

Comment: I am thinking what am i missing ? What can take birth from nose ? what type of living organisms can be born from nose ? did he mean something else when said nose , but nose was closest encryption of what he could find . I feel nose is an encryption of something more deep .

Comment: like i found the importance of number 18 . Bali attacked 18 places on indra , 10 on indras body , 4 on airavats legs , 3 on airavats three heads and one on mahaut . 10 - 10 indriyas(5+5)  3 purusharth , 4 satya dan daya suchi , 1 vivek totalling to 18 . 18 is a number of constitution  .